# Internet Explorer lowers text inside element with odd height

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have this element:

```css
.container {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.link {
  color: #3072c4;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.counter {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 9px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 17px;
    background: #FF8000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 17px;
}
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="link">
      Feedback
    </span>
      <span class="counter">166</span>
 </span>
```

Its height must be 17px, horizontal padding should be 4px and font size should be 12px. It looks like a prototype in Chrome and Firefox:

[image]

But there is a problem in Internet Explorer:

[image]

It lowers the text inside, it is not well aligned vertically. If I set line-height and width of element to 18px (as well as every other even value), everything is OK, but I need 17px. How to avoid text lowering in IE?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a specific style for IE. You can try this:

```css
.container {
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 20px;
      font-family: "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
      color: #3072c4;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .counter {
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 9px;
        padding: 0 4px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 17px;
        background: #FF8000;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 700;
        border-radius: 17px;
    }
    @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
      /* IE Edge 12+ CSS styles go here */  
      .counter {
          display: inline-block;
          min-width: 9px;
          padding: 0px 4px 1px 4px;
          text-align: center;
          line-height: 17px;
          background: #FF8000;
          color: #fff;
          font-size: 12px;
          font-weight: 700;
          border-radius: 17px;
        }
    }
```

```html
<span class="container">
  <span class="link">
      Feedback
    </span>
      <span class="counter">166</span>
 </span>
```